# What are the correlation between Actor model and Reactive Programming

Tags: programming-languages, distributed-systems, programming-paradigms

Could anyone explain the difference/relation between the **Actor model** and **Reactive programming**?

It seems that they are located at different levels of abstraction - one can design the interaction between the components of any distributed system using Actor approach, they would send messages, and inside the actors, write code in reactive style?

this question related to [How do Functional Reactive Programming and the Actor model relate to each other?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9038/how-do-functional-reactive-programming-and-the-actor-model-relate-to-each-other)

However, the answers wasn't clear enough, and my question relates reactive programming in general, not **F**RP in particular.

Comment: (English not being my 1st language, I might call it *relationship* or *relation* rather than *correlation*.)